# How to match this string with elisp regexp?

Tags: regular-expressions, org-mode

I'm writing an extension to open a custom link type in Org-mode with Kiwix URL. (Kiwix is an offline Wikipedia program). Here is my [kiwix.el source code](https://github.com/stardiviner/kiwix.el).

I created a `wiki:` link type for Org-mode.

Here is the link formats:

- `[[wiki:(library):query]]`
- `[[wiki:query]]`

links:

- `wiki:(zh):%E7%A6%85%E5%AE%97`
- `wiki:(en):linux`
- `wiki:linux`

And here is the elisp regexp:

```lisp
"\\(wiki\\):\\((\\(.*\\)):\\)?\\(.*\\)"
```

Here is my current function to handle the link:

```lisp
(defun org-wiki-link-open (link)
  "Open LINK in external wiki program."
  (cond ((string-match "\\(wiki\\):\\((\\(.*\\)):\\)?\\(.*\\)"  link) ; [[wiki:(library):query]]
         (let* ((type (match-string 1 link))
                ;; convert between libraries full name and abbrev.
                (library (cdr (assoc
                               (match-string 3 link)
                               kiwix-librarie-abbrev-list)))
                (query (match-string 4 link))
                (url (concat kiwix-server-url library "/A/" (url-encode-url (capitalize query)) ".html")))
           (browse-url url)))
        ((string-match "\\(wiki\\):\\(.*\\)"  link) ; [[wiki:query]]
         (let* ((type (match-string 1 link))
                (query (match-string 4 link))
                (url (concat kiwix-server-url kiwix-default-library "/A/" (url-encode-url (capitalize query)) ".html")))
           (browse-url url)))))

(defun org-wiki-link-export (link description format)
  "Export the wiki LINK with DESCRIPTION for FORMAT from Org files."
  (let* ((type (when (string-match "\\(.+\\):(\\(.+\\)?):\\(.*\\)" link)
                 (match-string 1 link)))
         (library (when (string-match "\\(.+\\):(\\(.+\\)?):\\(.*\\)" link)
                    (match-string 2 link)))
         ;; query need to be convert to URL encoding: "禅宗" https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%A6%85%E5%AE%97
         (query (url-encode-url
                 (or description
                     (when (string-match "\\(.+\\):(\\(.+\\)?):\\(.*\\)" link)
                       (match-string 3 link)))))
         ;; "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux"
         ;;         --
         ;;          ^- library: en, zh
         (path (concat "http://" library ".wikipedia.org/wiki/" query))
         (desc query))
    (when (stringp path)
      (cond
       ((eq format 'html) (format "<a href=\"%s\">%s</a>" path desc))
       ((eq format 'latex) (format "\\href{%s}{%s}" path desc))
       (t path)))))

(org-add-link-type "wiki" 'org-wiki-link-open 'org-wiki-link-export)
```

But this regexp is wrong, can't open those example links correctly.

- [[wiki:(en):Linux][Linux (wiki)]]
- [[wiki:Linux][Linux]]
- [[wiki:(zh):%E7%A6%85%E5%AE%97][禅宗]]

So I hope someone can help me to improve this regexp pattern and my function code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp should be `\\(wiki\\):\\(?:(\\([^:]*\\)):\\)?\\([^] \n\t\r]*\\)`.

You have with that:

- group 1: wiki
- non capturing group (`\(?:...\)`) for optional library
- group 2: library (`en` or `zh`)
- group 3: link? (match everything but `]`, space, tab, carriage return, linefeed by using `[^] \n\t\r]*`)

So, you have one group less (your code should be adapted to that).

As an optimization you should `string-match` once and use subsequent `match-string` for each group of interest.

Comment: If I optimize the `string-match`, how to write the function `org-wiki-link-open`?

Comment: The function `org-wiki-link-export` could be optimized, `org-wiki-link-open` looks ok.

Comment: I checked the new function, which is in latest code now (I mentioned the repo in question). But it does now open link now. Weird. Maybe this is not in question scope, but I think should not post a new question.

Comment: You have `(match-string 4 link)` if library was not given, should be `(match-string 3 link)`.

Comment: Also `org-wiki-link-export`is different to previous version. Check your library extract there. In the previous version you had it with parentheses and colon included. Maybe it's now a bit better? But what if library was not given?